# PHP: add missing keys between arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have following array keys values:

```
$arrData = array
(
    array(
        'a' => 'test',
        'c' => 1,
        'd' => 2,
        'e' => 'B'
    ),
    array(
        'c' => 1,
        'd' => 2,
        'e' => 'B'
    ),
    array(
        'b' => 'test2',
        'c' => 1,
        'd' => 2,
        'e' => 'B'
    )
);
```

So here I need to merged array into single with combining missing keys with single value array.
Can someone please help to get following output in single array?

```
$arrData = array
(
    array(
        'a' => 'test',
        'b' => 'test2',
        'c' => 1,
        'd' => 2,
        'e' => 'B'
    )
);
```

Thanking in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 6):

Just merge them and then sort on the key:

```
$arrData = array_merge(...$arrData);
ksort($arrData);
```

Instead of `...` you can use:

```
$arrData = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arrData);
```

If you really want the result to be multi-dimensional, then:

```
$arrData = [$arraData];
//or
$arrData = array($arrData);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) (or a simple foreach loop) to merge each of the subsequent array values with the first one:

```
$out = array_reduce($arrData, function ($c, $v) { return array_merge($c, $v); }, array());
print_r($out);

$out = array();
foreach ($arrData as $arr) {
    $out = array_merge($out, $arr);
}
print_r($out);
```

Output (for both examples):

```
Array (
  [a] => test
  [c] => 1
  [d] => 2
  [e] => B
  [b] => test2 
)
```

If you want to keep the keys in alphabetical order, you can use `ksort`:

```
ksort($out);
print_r($out);

Array (
  [a] => test
  [b] => test2 
  [c] => 1
  [d] => 2
  [e] => B
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OJYJQ)

Comment: That's the answer I was about to post. You can also use `ksort` to keep the keys in order (he seems to want that, tho I'm not sure this is mandatory).

Answer (score 1):

Using `array_walk` and `ksort`

```
$res=[];
array_walk($arrData, function($v,$k) use(&$res){
  $res = array_merge($res,$v);
});
ksort($res);
```

OR

You can use `foreach` and `array_column`

```
$keys = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
$res=[];
foreach($keys as $val){
   $res[$val] = array_column($arrData, $val)[0];
}
print_r($res);
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/5nQSS)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $arrData = array
(
    array(
        'a' => 'test',
        'c' => 1,
        'd' => 2,
        'e' => 'B'
    ),
    array(
        'c' => 1,
        'd' => 2,
        'e' => 'B'
    ),
    array(
        'b' => 'test2',
        'c' => 1,
        'd' => 2,
        'e' => 'B'
    )
);

$result_array = array();
foreach($arrData as $ad){

    foreach($ad as $key=>$value){


        if(!array_key_exists($key,$result_array)){
            $result_array[$key] = $value;
        }

    }
}

print_r($result_array);
?>
```